# Allocating memory for pointer to pointer to pointer in C

Tags: c, pointers, memory, memory-management

I am trying to allocate memory for triple pointer and I cannot make it right. I have pointer to pointer to char

```
char **words;
allocate(&words);
```

And I created method for memory allocation:

```
void allocate(char ***words){

    for (int i = 0; i < MAXWORDNUM; ++i)
        (*words)[i] = malloc(sizeof(char*) * MAXWORDNUM);

    for (int i = 0; i < MAXWORD; ++i)
        (**words)[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * MAXWORD);
}
```

As I understand I should allocate memory for pointers and then I should allocate memory for each char. For the above code I am getting error:

```
warning: incompatible pointer to integer conversion assigning
      to 'char' from 'void *' [-Wint-conversion]
        (**words)[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * MAXWORD);
```

How to make it work? 
Thank you

Comment: `(*words)[i] = ...` already a bad move. `*words` doesn't point to anything determinate at that point, so `(*words)[i]` is UB. The second loop simply has the indirection misguided.

Comment: this code is working well in my mac :(

Comment: @vaibhav: no, this code is invoking undefined behavior in your Mac.

Comment: If I understand your intent you're trying to allocate a `MAXWORDNUM x MAXWORDNUM` matrix of `char *`, each of which is allocated space to hold up to `MAXWORD` chars. Is that correct? If not, are you instead trying to allocate a simple pointer array of `MAXWORDNUM` elements, each of which is a `char*` pointing to memory `MAXWORD` in length?

Comment: @WhozCraig no,  I was trying to allocate MAXWORDNUM x MAXWORD 2D array of pointers to char...

Comment: It should be obvious that you code isn't doing that, since it allocates MAXWORDNUM `char*`s MAXWORDNUM times, then allocates MAXWORD chars MAXWORD times.

Comment: @PutinHuylo It at-first *looks* like you're simply trying to allocate an array of pointer-to-char, with each pointer allocated to an array of `MAXWORD` chars. (the missing nested for-loop not withstanding), and returning the whole thing as an out-parameter. For the record, it gets *much* clearer to do this if you use a local var for the allocation, then assigned it via dereference on the way out of the function.

Answer (score 4):

```
void allocate(char ***words){
    *words = malloc(sizeof(char*) * MAXWORDNUM);
    for (int i = 0; i < MAXWORDNUM; ++i)
        (*words)[i] = malloc(MAXWORD);
}
```

Comment: can you explain me how malloc(MAXWORD) works in this case? As I understand we need to provide size in bites...
Why in the first one we use sizeof(char*) * MAXWORDNUM, but here only MAXWORD?

Comment: You could do `malloc(sizeof(char) * MAXWORD)` but sizeof(char) is 1 so I omitted it.  The behavior will be identical if you prefer to be more specific.

Comment: I'm still lost on why `*words = malloc(sizeof(char*) * MAXWORDNUM)` is correct. `*words` is type `char**`. The size of pointers not withstanding, any any particular reason the core magnitude in the `malloc` is `sizeof(char*)` and not `sizeof(char**)` (or better still, `sizeof(*words)`)? Alter Mann's answer has a similar discrepancy. (my reading code *way* too late is a reasonable response, btw).

Comment: @WhozCraig `*words is type char**` -- so `(*words)[i]` is a `char*`, so of course one wants to allocate some number of `char*`s.

Comment: @JimBalter I'm must be seriously sleep deprived. Of course you're correct (as is John). `sizeof(**words)` should have been my first response from the get go (which is obviously `sizeof(char*)`. Ok. enough code for me. (and +1, John).

Comment: @WhozCraig For clarity, consistency, and type safety I always code this as `foo = malloc(sizeof *foo * N)`, so this would be `*words = malloc(sizeof **words * MAXWORDNUM)`

Comment: @JimBalter likewise, it was the lack of `**` that threw me. Following that consistently, particularly on the second nested allocation (though not needed) makes for some sometimes-fun code to read.

Comment: @WhozCraig Indeed `(*words)[i] = malloc(sizeof *(*words)[i] * MAXWORD)` is correct, and is necessary if words might contain something other than `char`s. I should say that, back when I coded in this obsolete language, I didn't actually do explicit mallocs, I used macros that took the lhs as a parameter and did the sizeof ... consistency is a programmer's friend.

Answer (score 3):

You want an array of pointers, not an array of array of pointers, the first loop is not needed:

```
void allocate(char ***words){
    /* for (int i = 0; i < MAXWORDNUM; ++i) */ 
    /* (m)allocate space for n pointers to words */
    *words = malloc(sizeof(char *) * MAXWORDNUM);

    for (int i = 0; i < MAXWORDNUM; ++i)
        (*words)[i] = malloc(MAXWORD); /* (m)allocate space for each word */
}

int main(void)
{
    char **words;

    allocate(&words);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your purpose, do you intend to create a 2-dimensional array, or a array of pointers, or just a pointer to pointer?

1) A 2-dimensional array

```
void allocate_two_dimen_array(char ***words, unsigned int x, unsigned int y){
    *word = malloc(x * y * sizeof(char));
}
```

2) A array of char pointers

```
void allocate_pointer_array(char ***words, unsigned int quantity){
    *word = malloc(quantity * sizeof(char*));
}
```

3) A pure pointer to char pointer

```
void allocate_pointer_pointer(char ***words){
    *word = malloc(sizeof(char**));
}
```

For practical purposes, for instance: the first one can be used to store a bmp image, the second one is used to store a set of strings

```
word = {"This is the first line", "This is the second line"};
```